# Why UIView animation doesn't work

Tags: objective-c

What I am trying to do is to programmatically create a UIView rectangle in upper left corner of screen, then move it to upper right, lower right, lower left, finally back to upper left. But it doesn't work as intended. What's wrong with my code?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *myView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myView = _myView;


- (IBAction)animation:(UIButton *)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        self.myView.alpha = 0.75;
        self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(160, 0, 160,230);}];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        self.myView.alpha = 0.50;
        self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(160, 230, 160,230);}];

     [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
     self.myView.alpha = 0.25;
     self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 230, 160,230);}];

     [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
     self.myView.alpha = 0.00;
     self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160,230);}
     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     [self.myView removeFromSuperview];
     }];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 230);
    UIView *mv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    self.myView = mv;
    self.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myView];

}
@end
```

**EDIT:
I fix the problem with nested completion blocks:**

```
- (IBAction)animation:(UIButton *)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        self.myView.alpha = 0.75;
        self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(160, 0, 160,230);}
     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
             self.myView.alpha = 0.50;
             self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(160, 230, 160,230);}
          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
              [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                  self.myView.alpha = 0.25;
                  self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 230, 160,230);}
          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
              [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                  self.myView.alpha = 0.00;
                  self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160,230);}
                               completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                   [self.myView removeFromSuperview];
          }];}];}];}];}
```

**Yet it's terrible to read. Is there any other way?**

Comment: try to start the next part of the animation _after_ the current part is finished, not in parallel with it. the poor `UIView` cannot decide what it should do. :)

Comment: Sounds interesting.. Could you be more specific and put the code in answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not the specific animation, but you should try this pattern to make the animations' parts launch after each other sequentially:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
    // first part of the animation
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        // second part of animation
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
            // third part of the animation
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                // forth part of the animation
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                // finish and clear the animation
            }];
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Shake hands. I just found the same. But nested blocks looks ugly. Any other way?

Comment: you could make it without blocks with finish-selectors, but the Apple strongly recommends the block-based animation in iOS4+.